# Out-of-the-box blog solultion for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, plugins, model, rubygems

Wordpress makes me want to make me close my head in a car door. I was wondering if there were any great out of the box blog's for rails.

At the moment I'm using a blend of act_as_ taggble, commentable, spam defence, sluggble etc and then rolling the url and routing myself in rails.

Does anyone know of any great act-as-bloggable style gems for rails?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/rblog
- http://www.enkiblog.com/

Just a fast google search, never use them. I suggest you to create your own blog engine. This is a super simple task with the rails.

Comment: Yeah I thought create your own would be the answer. Worth an ask.

Comment: im provide your couple of links. If you want awesome blog out of the box - use wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

http://refinerycms.com/

or

http://radiantcms.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Typo](http://fdv.github.com/typo/), perhaps.